# Cassandra Error : expected 8 or 0 byte long for date

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring data cassandra

My this code is working

```
@Query("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM notifications where userid = ?0 and typeofnotification=?1  "
            + "and notificationId > minTimeuuid('2019-09-12') and category = ?3 allow filtering")

    public Integer findCountForCategoryForDate(int userId, String typeOfNotification, String category);
```

But when i am trying to give date as param, it is giving error

```
@Query("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM notifications where userid = ?0 and typeofnotification=?1  "
            + "and notificationId > minTimeuuid(?2) and category = ?3 allow filtering")

public Integer findCountForCategoryForDate(int userId, String typeOfNotification,String date, String category);
```

What am i missing?

**notificationId column is timeuuid in DB**

Answer (score 4):

the `mintimeuuid` function expects timestamp as parameter, but you pass a string. You need to pass variable with `java.util.Date` type instead. See the [documentation for mapping between Java type and CQL types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping).

Comment: Thanks but already fixed it with Date. But wondering why it is not working with even java,util.LocalDate but working with java.util.Date

Comment: it could work, if you can add corresponding codec, as described here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/custom_codecs/extras/ - but that's extra package... In Java driver 4.x, the Instant is used for timestamps

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormatter then create date instance and assign that value to TimeStamp column. See [mapping between Java type and CQL types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping).

Enjoy :)